# 1.9 - Cron job failing

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I've setup a custom module that will automatically change the group of sellers on my site depending on their sales and orders. The script runs fine when manually executing it, however when setting up a cron for it, the cron continually dies according AOE Scheduler, with the message:
`TRIGGER: shutdown function` and the status `died`.

I have the following code:

`config.xml`

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Namespace_Autogroups>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Namespace_Autogroups>
</modules>
<global>

    <models>
        <namespace_autogroups>
            <class>Namespace_Autogroups_Model</class>
        </namespace_autogroups>
    </models>
</global>
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <switchsellergroup>
            <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>                
            <run><model>namespace_autogroups/cron::setSellerGroup</model></run>
        </switchsellergroup>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

`Cron.php`

```
class Namespace_Autogroups_Model_Cron
{
public function setSellerGroup()
{
  $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
  $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
  $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
  $table1 = $resource->getTableName('seller_payments');
  $table2 = $resource->getTableName('seller_group');

  $query = "SELECT $table1.vendor_id, SUM($table1.net_amount) AS sum, COUNT(*) as c, $table2.group_code, $table2.parent_id
  FROM $table1
  LEFT JOIN $table2 ON $table2.vendor_id = $table1.vendor_id
  GROUP BY vendor_id";

  $collection = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

  foreach($collection as $_seller) {
    $_seller['sum'] = $sellSum;
    $_seller['c'] = $orderSum;

    if (!$_seller['parent_id']){
    }


    elseif ($_seller['parent_id'] == 310) {
    }


    elseif ($_seller['parent_id'] == 35868) {
      if($sellSum >= 0 && $orderSum >= 0) {

        $vendorID = intval($_seller['vendor_id']);

        $queryG = "UPDATE {$table2} SET parent_id = 310, group_code = 'group3' WHERE vendor_id='$vendorID'";
        $writeConnection->query($queryG);
      }
      else {}

    }

    else {}



  } } }
```

The `($sellSum >= 0 && $orderSum >= 0)` is just for testing purposes to get it working. `parent_id` refers to the group id.

Is it the empty `else` statements?

Comment: Hi check this link  https://recordnotfound.com/Aoe-Scheduler-AOEpeople-52338/issues, it looks like it is an issue in AOE module. Try disabling it and run your cron. Also, let us know how you are setting up the cron job to run automatically.

Comment: What do you mean by how am I setting up the cron to run automatically? I have it set up in the `config.xml` with a schedule to run every 5 minutes (as shown above)

Comment: I finally got it working by changing `Cron.php` to `Observer.php` and making the necessary changes in the code. Would be awesome if someone could explain why this was necessary!